# index.php is on main url after last update

Tags: magento2.2.6, index.php

After we did the last update to Magento our homepage url went from

https://dutchmanaxles.com

to

https://dutchmanaxles.com/index.php

This only appears on the main page, and we have done all the steps in Magento to stop this from happening. Probably why index.php doesn't appear on any other page

Answer (score 1):

Stores > Configuration > Web > Search Engine Optimization > Use Web Server Rewrites

It should be "YES"

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have issue at `.htacces`.

Due to upgrade to `.htaccess` file is updated your system.

Might be `RewriteBase /` is not exits at your new.htaccess file.

It should be  open like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    RewriteBase /
```